# Remove all nodes with the same occurrences of the given string from doubly linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

Am trying to remove all occurrences of a given string. This code remove one node,but all others stays. i tried to wrap it in a while loop, but still no effets.

I also wanna know, if its possible to remove the struct argument and still make it happend.I tried to remove it and modified the code, but i get a segmentation error. Thank you for answers in advance.

```
void deleteNode(struct node** head, char* searchName) {

        struct node* current;
        for(current=*head; current; current = current->next){
            if (!strcmp(current->name, searchName))
            {
            if (current->next)
                current->next->prev = current->next;
                if (current->prev)
                current->prev->next = current->prev;
                if (current == *head)
                *head = current->next;
                current->prev = NULL;
                current->next = NULL;
                free(current);
                return;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have Valgrind available?  If so, use it.  Do you have code to print your lists?  If so, you can use it to check your result at appropriate stages.  The `return` is why you are only removing at most one node.  The assignments to `current->prev` and `current->next` before freeing the memory are redundant (not harmful, but not necessary either).

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement will end the function after the first hit. Also the sequence `current->next = NULL; free(current); current = current->next` will access memory after it was freed and also set current to NULL. You may need to update `current` inside the loop and use one extra node pointer variable for the deletion.

```
void deleteNode(struct node** head, char* searchName)
{
    struct node* current;
    struct node* to_delete;
    for(current=*head; current;)
    {
        if (!strcmp(current->name, searchName))
        {
            to_delete = current;
            current = current->next;
            if (current) {
                current->prev = to_delete->prev;
            }
            if (to_delete->prev) {
                to_delete->prev->next = current;
            }
            if (to_delete == *head)
                *head = current;
            free(to_delete);
        } else {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point on the loop reinitialization step accessing freed memory that was set NULL.  That won't help anything!

Comment: ok, I shuffled the disconnection bit around, how about now?

Comment: Neither have I :)

Comment: Thank you guys! but i figured it out right after i got the hint with return part! @JonathanLeffler.

Comment: thanks to you @dratenik, I still wondering if i can remove the argument in the method?`the one with struct node** head. and only pass searchname

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow yes, my pointer for head variable is global. Am just curios if it can work. haha

Answer (score 0):

Your function is wrong. For example this if statement

```
 if (current->next)
            current->next->prev = current->next;
```

shall be rewritten like

```
 if (current->next)
            current->next->prev = current->prev;
                                           ^^^^
```

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void deleteNode( struct node **head, const char *searchName )
{
    while ( *head )
    {
        if ( strcmp( ( *head )->name, searchName ) == 0 )
        {
            struct node *current = *head;
            if ( current->next ) current->next->prev = current->prev;
            *head = current->next;
            
            free( current );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Pay attention to if the data member `name` of the structure `struct node`  points to a dynamically allocated memory that stores a string then before calling the function `free` for the pointer `current` in the above function you have to free the memory allocated for the string. That is you need to add one more call of the function `free` like

```
free( current->name );
free( current );
```

If you have a global pointer to the head node named for example `head` then the function can be defined the following way

```
void deleteNode( const char *searchName )
{
    struct node **head_ref = &head;

    while ( *head_ref )
    {
        if ( strcmp( ( *head_ref )->name, searchName ) == 0 )
        {
            struct node *current = *head_ref;
            if ( current->next ) current->next->prev = current->prev;
            *head_ref = current->next;
            
            free( current );
        }
        else
        {
            head_ref = &( *head_ref )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vlad from Moscow. Can i ask how you would done it without the Node given in the argument?

Comment: @NotsureAnymore It can be done only when the pointer to the head node is a global variable. But such an approach is not good. Are the pointer to the head node in your project global?

Comment: Ahh i see, thank you so much !! i have another function, but it only for return index of the node with the given string. It always jump to that the element dosent exists in list. Shall i post it here? or shall i create a new question? @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: @NotsureAnymore It will be better to ask a new question.

Comment: i see you have your email put in yuor profile, can i reach out to you :D ? @ Vlad from Moscow

Comment: @NotsureAnymore You can but if you have questions it will be better to ask them at SO.

Comment: I got a problem. When I delete the last node in liste, the first node also disspears. The one in the middle stays the same tho 

Comment: @NotsureAnymore I to see your code. It can be a problem related with other functions. You should close the question and ask a new one with your current code.